# mongoDB is getting slower and slower

Tags: performance, mongodb

I update data into MongoDB continuously in different collection or DB, which name are timestamp. And I delete the oldest data and keep about 3 days data, 200GB,  in mongo. The mapped and vsize are increasing but res is under 10 GB. And I summarize the mongo response time  is larger and larger.  Do you know the reason? I am willing your sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that you are using indexes correctly.

For example, if you find users by `email` field, you have to build index for this field:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({ email: 1 })
```

To learn more about indexes please follow the link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/

Also, some explanation will be very useful for you. You can see detailed information about your queries from the next command:

```
db.users.find({ email: "user@example.com" }).explain()
```

`explain()` will say you a lot about your query. To read more about it, please follow the official documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

So, if you are sure that indexes are built correctly, please post the output of `explain()`. It will help us to find the problem.